# Cannot locate .wslconfig in user profile on windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, ubuntu-22.04

I am completely new to Docker and Linux Subsystem on Windows [Ubuntu 22.04.1], which requires changing the CPU and RAM used in Docker, and I'm trying resolve a [Parallel Computing on Windows
Problem](https://degauss.org/troubleshooting.html#Parallel_Computing_on_Windows); however, as noted in the troubleshooting guide and on the Docker Settings' Advanced suboption in Resources, I need to change the `.wslconfig` file:

- I followed [Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconfig), but there is no file or folder within:

  ```
  %UserProfile%\.wslconfig
  ```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Since it’s missing you can create it, if the contents are invalid, it will be ignored. *If the file is missing or malformed (improper markup formatting), WSL will continue to launch as normal without the configuration settings applied.* which is from the link you provided

Comment: @Ramhound, so if I create the folder, would I then be able to change the CPU and RAM used so I can proceed with the parallel computing step from the first link? Is there anything I should put in the folder?


Docker does not let me change the CPU or RAM usage unless I change `.wslconfig`

Comment: @Ramhound apologies for the follow up comment, at the bottom of the microsoft link there is an example, what type of file should I save it as and for an Ubuntu subsystem would the CPU I want it to use = 1?

Comment: The filename is [`.wslconfig`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/wsl/blob/main/WSL/wsl-config.md)

Comment: @Ramhound and the file type is a text document? processors = CPU?

Comment: The contents of the file, which has a filename of exactly `.wslconfig` does indeed contain text.  Why are you not using `wsl.conf` instead of `.wslconfig`? `.wslconfig` overrides the `wsl.conf`. It seems you have some research to do, you are asking me questions, and I have linked you to the documentation on the file in question. The answer to your question about limiting ALL WSL2 distributions to a single processor would be `processors=1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142404/discussion-between-ramhound-and-ineedhelp).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Any advice on how to fix this?

1. Create file: [`%UserProfile%\.wslconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)
2. Within `%UserProfile%\.wslconfig`, paste:

   ```ini
   [wsl2]
   memory=4GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4 GB
   processors=2 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
   ```
3. Since you are unlikely to be compiling and creating your own WSL2 Linux kernel, I have removed the line that sets the custom kernel that *ALL* WSL2 distributions would use.